# Hypergeometric Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

A manufacturer receives a lot of many parts from a vendor. The lot will be unacceptable
if more than five percent the parts are defective. The manufacturer is going to select
randomly K parts from the lot for inspection and the lot will be accepted if at most
one defective part is found in the sample. Suppose exactly five percent of the parts are
defective.

(a) How large does K have to be to ensure that the probability that this lot is accepted is less than 10%?

(b) How does your answer to (a) change if the lot is accepted if at most two defective parts are found in the sample?

I'm a little confused on how to solve this. Let's say the total number of parts in the lot is T and the number of defective parts is D. Since exactly five percent of the parts are defective than D = T/20. Let's say X is the number of defective parts in the sample. Then I think X ~ Hypergeom(T, D, K). For part A am I just getting f(X=0) + f(X=1) < 0.10? Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Assume the size of the lot is *much larger* than whatever $K$ will be, and that the sample is *representative* of the lot. $~$ What is the distribution for a count of successes among a sample of size $K$ when the success rate is $5\%$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The question is posed in a way that suggests a hypergeometric distribution, because the sampling technically is performed without replacement, but because the population (number of parts in the lot) is not specified and is only said to be "many parts," the appropriate model to use is binomial.

Specifically, let $K$ be the number of parts to be drawn from the lot.  Then let $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = K, p = 0.05)$$ represent the random number of defective parts found among the sampled parts.  We use $p = 0.05$ because we are told that $5\%$ of the parts are defective.  Then $$\Pr[X \le 1] = \binom{K}{0} p^0 (1-p)^K + \binom{K}{1} p^1 (1-p)^{K-1} = (0.95)^K + K(0.05)(0.95)^{K-1} \tag{1}$$ is the probability that the lot is accepted.  We require this to be less than $0.1$.  Clearly, as $K$ increases, this probability also increases (the more you sample, the more likely you are to find a defective part in your sample).  So the idea is to find the *smallest* positive integer $K$ that makes $(1)$ less than $0.1$.  I leave this to the reader to compute; however, be aware that the computation involves a bit of trial-and-error.

The second part of the question is solved in much the same way; we just need to solve $$\Pr[X \le 2] \le 0.1.$$  Note that the minimum $K$ in this case will be larger than the one found in the first part, since we are now more tolerant of defects, thus more likely to accept the lot for a given sample size, thus will need to sample more parts in order to maintain the same probability of acceptance.  Again I leave the computational details to the reader.

Going back to the hypergeometric model, what would happen if we tried to use it?  One way would be to let $d$ represent the number of defective parts in the lot, hence $L = 20d$ represents the total lot size, as the defect proportion is $5\%$ as we noted earlier.  This means $19d$ parts are acceptable.  If as before we sample $K$ parts without replacement, and let $X$ represent the number of defects found, then $$X \sim \operatorname{Hypergeometric}(K, d, 20d), \\ \Pr[X = x] = \frac{\binom{d}{x}\binom{19d}{K-x}}{\binom{20d}{K}}. \tag{2}$$  And as before, we would need to find the largest $K$ such that $$\Pr[X \le 1] = \frac{\binom{19d}{K} + d \binom{19d}{K-1}}{\binom{20d}{K}} \le 0.1. \tag{3}$$  Clearly, we have a problem:  the solution to this inequality depends on the choice of $d$.  We could in theory solve $(3)$ for $K$ in terms of $d$, but this is not feasible in practice as there is no closed-form expression.

We can use $(3)$ to compute the minimum $K$ for specific choices of $d$ to illustrate that the answer under a hypergeometric model does in fact depend on $d$; moreover, we can also show how the hypergeometric model tends to the binomial in the limit $d \to \infty$.  For instance, if $d = 2$, then $(3)$ becomes $$\frac{(40-K)(39-K)}{1560} \le 0.1$$ which gives us the unique positive root $K = (1 + \sqrt{5617})/2 \approx 37.9733$, hence $K \ge 38$; i.e., we would have to sample at least $38$ out of the $L = 20d = 40$ parts in the lot.  If $d = 10$, then numerical methods show that we need to sample $K \ge 67$ out of $L = 200$ parts in the lot.